# i created a class but when i call its properties it returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I don't know what seems to be the problem. Can anyone enlighten me on why is my class returns as undefined?

```
function ToDo() {
  class clsToDo{
    constructor(description) {
      this.description = description;
      this.complete = false;
    }
  }
  return clsToDo;
}

desc = 'Create ToDo';
newToDo = new ToDo(desc);

console.log(newToDo.description); // this should print 'Create ToDo'
```

Comment: Just get rid of the function wrapping your class, a Class is a construct on it's own it does not need to be returned by a function, see: [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)
You are trying to create an instance of a function not a class

Comment: ^^ what @empiric said. But **if** you wanted to have `ToDo` return the class, the way you'd use that is `new ToDo()(desc)`. But that's very unusual; do what @empiric said.

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but that code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you call just function that returns class:

```js
function ToDo() {
  class clsToDo{
    constructor(description) {
      this.description = description;
      this.complete = false;
    }
  }
  return clsToDo;
}

desc = 'Create ToDo';
newToDo = new ToDo(desc);
v = new newToDo('ok');

console.log(newToDo)

console.log(v.description);
```

---

Drop your function and just use [normal class definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#class_body_and_method_definitions):

```js
class ToDo {
    constructor(description) {
      this.description = description;
      this.complete = false;
    }
  };

desc = 'Create ToDo';
newToDo = new ToDo(desc);

console.log(newToDo.description);
```

Comment: Probably best to fix the implicit globals as well. :-) (Also, `class` declarations don't have `;` after them.)